# Uninstalled Python3.6, now apt install/get/ and dpkg errors

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

Running ubuntu 16.10.

I removed Python3.6 (I had 3.5 and didn't want 3.6) and now I get dpkg and apt errors all over the place. Can't even do `lsb_release -a` without getting `-bash: /usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links.`

If I try to for example (re)install Python3 (or do anything with apt for that matter) I get the following:
https://pastebin.com/im1bxc1R

I've tried (re)installing various Python versions, and the packages shown at the end of the pastebin.

I've even tried to manually download and install Python3.6, but when I run the last command `sudo make install` I get this at the end: https://pastebin.com/DYynaiKe

Thanks in advanced, and please help :(

Edit 1: 
The original Python3.6 was installed by the following:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

The manual download/install (after the problems began):

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
tar xJf ./Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
cd ./Python-3.6.1
./configure 
make && sudo make install
```

Comment: How you fix the problem depends upon exactly how you installed Python 3.6 originally. Please edit your question to explain exactly how you installed Python 3.6. Blindly installing and uninstalling python packages is likely to make the problem worse, not better.

Comment: Updated! hope it helps